# Get public posts from page which we dont manage

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'd like to pull public posts from page and tried to use `{page_id}/publised_posts` but got this error

```
{
    "error": {
        "message": "(#210) A page access token is required to request this resource.",
        "type": "OAuthException",
        "code": 210,
        "fbtrace_id": "AT22q6NqASn_ZFWNudbIVht"
    }
}
```

May i know what api is used for get public posts from page we dont manage (use without manage_pages permission) ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply for [Page Public Content Access](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/feature#reference-PAGES_ACCESS). After that, use an App Access Token with the `/page-id/posts` endpoint to get public posts.

Comment: do we need request permission about page from user ?